# taskstackbuilder for api 14

Tags: android, activity-stack

My compiler show this message...

> Call required API level 16 (current min is 14)

The question is.. **"Is this code is okay to run in api 14 or not??"**
because I have no device to test this API version since AVD doesn't have GPS (Requirement)
Do I have to implement support library or not??

**NOTE**

It works perfectly on API 16 and above

**TaskStackBuilder**

```
    PendingIntent contentIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
            // add all of DetailsActivity's parents to the stack,
            // followed by DetailsActivity itself
            .addParentStack(Activity_TrackingMode.class)
            .addNextIntent(new Intent(this, Activity_TrackingMode.class))
            .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
    <activity android:name=".Activity_TrackingMode"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:parentActivityName=".Activity_Screen1">
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".Activity_Screen1" />
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuider`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html

to run on API 14

Comment: android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuider ?

Comment: Okay I add this line and issue was resolve thank!

> import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;